Reach this size in a year
i’m 23 at around 180cm and 80kg
I’ve been trying to reach this size for a bit but i always stagnate, either by stopping working out or not reaching the calorie needed.
Been doing research and i found that alex leonidas, ie alpha destinies way might be the way to go, by training 2x a week and eating surplus calories..
What do you think the best way to reach thisenter link description here goal?
